# What does $f|_V$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I want to proof: If $W$ is vector space, $U, V \subseteq W$ linear subspaces, and $f : W \rightarrow Z$ is homomorphism, $\ker f \subseteq U$ and $W = U \oplus V$ then $f|_V : V \rightarrow Im(f|_V)$ is isomorphism.

I'm sure this is quite easy to proof. But I don't know what $f|_V$ means. Is it just another function? Or is it somehow a special version of the function $f$?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It is $f$ restricted to $V$. So it's just like $f$ but with a smaller domain.

Comment: It's the function that has the same value as $f$ on the subspace V (and we don't know anything about its values outside V)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means $f$ restricted to $V$, i.e., as a mapping acting only on members of $V$ rather than all of $W$.

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition if $\mathbf{R}$ is a relation and $A$ is a set then $$\mathbf{R}|_{A}=\{(x,y)\mid x\mathbf{R}y~~\wedge~~x\in A\}$$ For a simple example, if $$\mathbf{R}=\{(1,2),(a,2),(0,5),(1,1)\},~~~A=\{1,5,3,0\}$$ then $$\mathbf{R}|_{A}=\{(1,2),(1,1),(0,5)\}$$

Answer (score 1):

It is the composition of $f$ with the inclusion map of $V$ into $W$